# calculate standard deviation by month

Tags: excel, if-statement, variance, array-formulas

I am trying to calculate standard deviation by month from daily data. I used this function and it's not working (It's returning `%DIV/0!`).

```
{=STDEV.S(IF(AND(MONTH(data!$A$5:$A$3893)=MONTH($I22),YEAR(data!$A$5:$A$3893)=YEAR($I22)),data!H$5:H$3893,0))}
```

Can you help me about this?

Thanks

Comment: not working **HOW**?

Comment: Oh I got this error #DIV/0!

Comment: Check your values. Reduce the range to just 2 rows that you know for sure have proper values and see if that works

Comment: Thanks Amit, just tried that. but still not working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AND function as used in your formula will combine the month and year tests instead of applying them separately. Use cascading IFs to avoid this. Also, using zero for the case where the IF is false will probably give the wrong standard deviation, because

```
STDEV.P(1,2,3,0,0,0,0,0) <> STDEV.P (1,2,3).
```

Try this:

```
=STDEV.S(IF(MONTH(data!$A$5:$A$3893)=MONTH($I22),IF(YEAR(data!$A$5:$A$3893)=YEAR($I22),data!H$5:H$3893,"NO"),"NO"))
```

The "NO" 's in the formula can be any text. When Excel's statistical functions (SUM, AVG, STDEV, etc) encounter a text value, they skip it instead of converting it to zero.

```
STDEV.P(1,2,3,"NO","NO","NO","NO","NO") == STDEV.P(1,2,3)!!!
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `AND` doesn't work well with array formulas. Replace it with a multiplication. Also, remove the 0 in the false part of the if so that it won't ruin your computation:

```
{=STDEV.S(IF((MONTH(data!$A$5:$A$3893)=MONTH($I22)) *
  (YEAR(data!$A$5:$A$3893)=YEAR($I22)), data!H$5:H$3893))}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you can't use the AND operator in an array formula (since it tries to combine all the values into a single true or false).

Also by using 0 as your false value you are introducing false readings.  Use a text value instead which stdev.s ignores.

Try
   `{=STDEV.S(IF(MONTH(data!$A$5:$A$3893)=MONTH($I22),if(YEAR(data!$A$5:$A$3893)=YEAR($I22),data!H$5:H$3893,""),""))}`